# Change values inside aggregate function based on a value in another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

I have two queries. The first one just list the individual rows and if CANCELCODE is 1 then makes another field negative like this:

```
  CASE t.CancelCode
       WHEN '1'
       THEN t.Quantity * -1
       ELSE t.Quantity
   END AS Quantity,...
```

The 2nd query SUMs up the total but how can I make it check for the condition like above ?

```
     SUM(t.Quantity) AS Quantity, --case t.cancelcode is 1 then negative the value
```

Is there a way to do this or should I put the first set of results in a temp table and then use that since at that point the value is negative/positive as needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SUM(CASE t.CancelCode WHEN '1'
        THEN t.Quantity * -1
        ELSE t.Quantity
    END) AS Quantity,...
```

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap your case statement in your SUM function:-

```
SUM(CASE WHEN t.CancelCode = '1' THEN t.Quantity * -1 ELSE t.Quantity END) AS Quantity
```

Answer (score 1):

Use apply, this is more efficient if you need to use that case more than once

```
select sum(a.Quantity)
from yourtable t
cross apply (
select CASE t.CancelCode
       WHEN '1'
       THEN t.Quantity * -1
       ELSE t.Quantity
   END AS Quantity
) a
```